# Div Target/Active Transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm unable to get a div to expand on click and I can only get it to work when I use hover. I tried wrapping the div in an  but no dice. Any tips?

CSS

```
.membershipwrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    background: #dadada;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s linear .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s linear .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s linear .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s linear .3s;
    transition: all .3s linear .3s;
}
.membershipwrap:hover {
    height: 150px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="membershipwrap">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Test</a></p>
  <p>a;sdjf;jksdfkjas;dfj;safdj</p>
  <p>;klasdjf;kajs;dflklsafdj;kasjdfk;asjf</p>
  <p>;ksdjf;lkasdfjak;sdjfka;dfjs</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll have to use some javascript or jquery to do it on click -- `:active` would be the closest you could get to it, unless you wanted to put a random `target` somewhere and link to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this would be the only way to do it without any jquery or javascript.

**HTML**

```
<!--// wrap the whole thing in an an a tag that points to an id on the div (can be anything) //-->
<a href="#random">
<div class="membershipwrap" id="random">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Test</a></p>
  <p>a;sdjf;jksdfkjas;dfj;safdj</p>
  <p>;klasdjf;kajs;dflklsafdj;kasjdfk;asjf</p>
  <p>;ksdjf;lkasdfjak;sdjfka;dfjs</p>
</div>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
    .membershipwrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 50px;
    background: #dadada;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s linear .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s linear .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s linear .3s;
    -o-transition: all .3s linear .3s;
    transition: all .3s linear .3s;
}
/* add :target */
.membershipwrap:target {
    height: 150px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/H2sJt/)**

Or, if you wanted it to expand and collapse on each click, you could do it with regular old fashioned javascript...

**CSS**

```
.expanded {
    height: 150px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var el = document.getElementById("wrap");
el.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(this.className.indexOf('expanded') === -1){
        this.className += ' expanded';
    }
    else {
        this.className = 'membershipwrap'
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/H2sJt/1/)**

Or with JQuery...

**JQuery**

```
$('.membershipwrap').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
});
```

**[Moar Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/H2sJt/3/)**

Comment: I bet now OP wants to close it when clicked again

Comment: Yeah, maybe... That won't happen with just css though. Also, they didn't mention that in the OP.

Comment: Added the Javascript that would do that... And some Jquery, just for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

Specify `:active` on the div's css. The div will expand when clicked and collapse when it's not being clicked.

```
.membershipwrap:active {
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: That'll only work if the click is held down the whole time. Hardly likely that's what OP wants